# When use ComponentDidMount() I found this error : Can't call setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I found this error :

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Context : When I'm connected, I'm on the homepage, this page not contain the breadCrumb, but If I go on `CampaignPage` (also the name of the component), I have the `BreadCrumb` (Component name) I found this error.

On other post what I could see, they said probably problem on asynchronously on `ComponentWillMount` but I think my problem is different and I can't find a solution.

My code look like that :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import {
  BREADCRUMBS_ROUTES,
  BREADCRUMBS_ROUTES_FOR_ID,
  BREADCRUMBS_ENDPOINT
} from 'constants';
import { getEntityById, setUpdatedBreadcrumbs } from 'actions/breadcrumbs';

import style from './style.scss';

class Breadcrumbs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      breadcrumbs: [],
      names: {}
    };

    this.setBreadcrumbs = this.setBreadcrumbs.bind(this);
    this.loadEntityNameById = this.loadEntityNameById.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setBreadcrumbs();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { isWillUpdate: newIsWillUpdate } = nextProps;
    const { isWillUpdate, saveUpdatedBreadcrumbs } = this.props;

    if (isWillUpdate === false && newIsWillUpdate === true) {
      this.setBreadcrumbs();
      saveUpdatedBreadcrumbs();
    }
  }


  setBreadcrumbs() {
    const { params, path } = this.props.match;
    let currentPath = '';

    const pathSplitedAndExtendet = path.split('/')
      .filter(item => !!item)
      .map(item => {
        if (item[0] === ':' && item.slice(1) !== 'adPage') {
          const parameterName = item.slice(1);
          this.loadEntityNameById(
            parameterName,
            params[parameterName]
          );

          return {
            route: `/${params[parameterName]}${BREADCRUMBS_ROUTES_FOR_ID[parameterName]}`,
            parameter: parameterName
          };
        }
        return {
          route: `/${item}`,
          parameter: ''
        };
      });

    const breadcrumbs = pathSplitedAndExtendet
      .filter(item => item.parameter !== 'adPage')
      .map((item) => {
        const indexOfRoute = currentPath.indexOf(item.route);
        if (currentPath.slice(indexOfRoute) !== item.route) {
          currentPath = `${currentPath}${item.route}`;
        }

        return ({
          ...item,
          name: BREADCRUMBS_ROUTES[item.route] || '',
          route: currentPath
        });
      });
    this.setState({ breadcrumbs });
  }

  async loadEntityNameById(parameter, id) {
    const { loadEntityById } = this.props;
    await loadEntityById(BREADCRUMBS_ENDPOINT[parameter], id)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ names: objectAssign(this.state.names, { [parameter]: { id, name: data.name } }) });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { breadcrumbs, names } = this.state;
    const { showBreadcrumbs } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={style.breadcrumbs}>
        {
          showBreadcrumbs && breadcrumbs
            .map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={`${item.name}--${item.route}--${index}`}
                  className={classnames(style.bread, index === breadcrumbs.length - 1 ? style.last : null)}
                  role="link"
                  tabIndex={-10 - index}
                  onKeyDown={() => {}}
                  onClick={item.route ? () => this.props.history.push(item.route) : null}
                >
                  {`${item.name || (names[item.parameter]
                    ? names[item.parameter].name : '...')}
                    ${((breadcrumbs.length > 1) && (index !== breadcrumbs.length - 1)) ? ' >' : ''}
                  `}
                </div>
              );
            })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Breadcrumbs));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

This error message clearly states that your application has memory leak. What's going on here exactly?

Well, you're using async operation (loadEntityNameById) in `setBreadcrumbs` method. Which is being called in `componentWillMount` and in `componentWillReceiveProps`. This means when you go from `CampaignPage` component to `BreadCrumb` component, it will do the async operation ie. `loadEntityNameById` is running in the background which only sets the state once it's finished. But until that time your `BreadCrumb` component might be unmounted. The react application doesn't allow you to update the state on an unmounted component.

Furthermore, you should not use `componentWillMount` method at all. Use `componentDidMount` hook instead.

To fix the issue, what you can do is to set a flag like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // component is mounted, set the didMount property on BreadCrumb component
  // you can use any name instead of didMount what you think is proper
  this.didMount = true
  // now, you can update the state
  if(this.didMount) { // be sure it's not unmounted
    this.setState({names: ...})
  }
```

Next, you should clear the didMount property when the component is unmounted.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.didMount = false // component is unmounted
```

This will ensure you that your application memory will not be leaked. Because, we properly setting the state when required but not when it doesn't require, and stopping unnecessary loop.

Comment: How can I use the value from the return of my promise from my async/await operation into the `componentDidMount` for using setState.

Or maybe moving all the function into the componentDidMount ?

Comment: You can use either way.

Comment: Thanks you I will try tomorrow at the office !

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. 
I made a global variable like `this.didMount` set a true, as you told me and in my async/await function before `this.setState` I check if `this.didMount` equal true, if true, I can use `this.setState` otherwise nothing happen. 

I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an asynchronous action (`loadEntityNameById`) that sets the state for the component when it finishes. By that time, your `Breadcrumbs` component may have been unmounted, and the error is thrown.

Comment: You can advice for me ? 
If I unmounted `loadEntityNameById` ?

Comment: Hope this article can explain some strategies https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `setState` in `componentWillMount` try using `componentDidMount` instead

Comment: Ok thanks, but it's a minor problem, I fixed that after when we found a solution for this problem