# How should I initialize loading flags in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-page-application

With this simple example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    loading: false
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      this.setState({ items: data, loading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <p>loading...</p>
    ) : (
      this.state.items.map(i => <p key={i.id}>item</p>)
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here I'm initializing the loading flag as false so the first time the component is rendered, we'll see the empty array rendered until componentDidMount is called and the "loading" is shown. This is a simple example so maybe this doesn't matter here, but I have situations where I don't want this to happen.

One simple solution would be setting the initial flag value to true, but I don't know whether this is an appropriate solution. Maybe there is another better way to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: what is it about this that you don't like? I guess I am unclear with what your'e asking.

Comment: This will help you which I just answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969913/when-use-componentdidmount-i-found-this-error-cant-call-setstate/51970941#51970941

Comment: @ChaimFriedman I don't want the array to be rendered before the api call is completed

Comment: @PedroBrost I think your code is fine..

Comment: If you don't want the array rendered then make it conditional, such as:

    { this.state.items.length > 0 && this.state.items.map(i => <p key={i.id}>item</p>) }

Comment: Are you saying putting `loading` is .a bad idea? Or do you mean the array might be empty in cases where you don't have the `loading` flag in the component?

Comment: @yaswanth I'm not saying that using the flag si a bad idea. I just don't want to render the whole app the first time without the data fetched from the api. This happens because loading is set to false the first time the app is rendered

Comment: So you don't want the component to be rendered until you fetch the data?

Comment: I want to see "loading" until the data is fetched without this super short first render

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Even without `react`, how do you plan to do that? You either remove the `Loading` element from DOM or hide the element once your API loads data. That does more computation compared to what `react` does. You can read https://medium.com/@hidace/understanding-reacts-virtual-dom-vs-the-real-dom-68ae29039951

Answer (score 0):

Just set `loading: true` initially.  Nothing wrong with that.