# setState not working inside axios fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, nodes, axios

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {items: null }
    this.fetchImages = this.fetchImages.bind(this)
  }


  fetchImages()
  {
    var self = this

    axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=')
      .then(function (result)  {
        const items = result
        self.setState({ items: 'test' })
      });

  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.fetchImages()
    console.log(this.state.items)
  }

  render () {

    return (

      <div>Test</div>


    );

  }
}
```

I set `items` to `null` and `console.log` with `null` still appearing 
I've tried logging the result and I get my data Im looking for help please!
Also have tried using arrow function in es6 still doesn't `setState`

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchImages()`? Where are you logging the result?

Comment: in componentDidMount

Comment: Can you show the rest of your component code?

Comment: Where are you checking if state is set or not? Because setState is an asynchronous function call. Immediately after the setState function is invoked, the new state will not be seen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When use ComponentDidMount() I found this error : Can't call setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969913/when-use-componentdidmount-i-found-this-error-cant-call-setstate)

Comment: So a couple of things: 1) You don't need to alias this to self 2) As @Vicky says you are checking your state before it is actually set. You can use the callback that setState accepts to log state

Comment: yeah I console logged after the function call

Comment: Even console.log immediately after setState function call won't give new state. You can see the new state value in render () function though!

Comment: Thanks @Vicky I was pulling hair out on that one.

Comment: :) Welcome. Enjoy React :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's gather all the comments and suggestions then provide an answer :)

Your main problem, as said in the comments, logging your state in the wrong place. Since `setState` is asynchronous, right after putting a `console.log` did not work. Here, you have two options.

First one is using a callback in your `setState` method.

```
self.setState({ items: "test" }, () => console.log(this.state.items))
```

Your second option is using `console.log` in your `render` method.

```
render () {
    console.log( this.state.items );
    return (
    ...
```

So, in the first render, you see the initial value, after the update you see the data.
Remember, never use `setState` in the `render` method but logging your state is OK here.

The second problem, not actually a problem but not necessary maybe, you don't need to use `var self = this` in your function. If you use an arrow function instead of the regular one, you can directly use `this` there since arrow functions do not create own scopes.

```
axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=')
    .then( result => this.setState({ items: 'test' })
);
```

So, your whole component would be something like that:

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { items: null }
    this.fetchImages = this.fetchImages.bind(this)
  }

  fetchImages() {
    axios.get( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=" )
      .then(result => this.setState({ items: "test"} )
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImages();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state.items );
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}
```

If you have proper Babel plugins and configuration, you can even use class-fields proposal to simplify your code.

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {
  state = { items: null };

  fetchImages() {
    axios.get( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=" )
      .then((result) => this.setState({ items: "test"} )
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImages();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}
```

As in the current situation, you don't need to bind your function. But remember, if you use this `fetchImages` in a **callback** (like in a button) you will need to bind it. If you use an arrow function it is bond automatically.

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {
  state = { items: null };

  fetchImages = () =>
      axios.get( "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=" )
      .then((result) => this.setState({ items: "test"} )
    );

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImages();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}
```